# Unable to find Taglib with find_package in CMake when installed through vcpkg

Tags: c++, cmake, taglib, vcpkg

I've installed `taglib` with manifest mode, but am unable to use `find_package(Taglib)` (I've tried taglib, Taglib, TagLib, etc). I get the following error

```
CMake Error at vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:853 (_find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Taglib" with any
  of the following names:

    TaglibConfig.cmake
    taglib-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Taglib" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Taglib_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Taglib"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:40 (find_package)
```

There seems to be no "taglib" variables exported at all, `Taglib_DIR` has the value `Taglib_DIR-NOTFOUND`.

I've had that issue before with other packages, but some combination of rebuilding/reinstalling, executing the bootstrap script or random other fiddling solved it so far. I see a `taglib-config.cmake` in `./vcpkg/buildtrees/taglib/src/v1.13-5298fc2c7f.clean/taglib-config.cmake`, and another in `./vcpkg/buildtrees/taglib/x64-linux-rel/taglib-config` (not a .cmake file).

Other packages installed through vcpkg typically have a config file defined in `vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/share/<package>`, like `vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/share/immer/ImmerConfig.cmake`, but taglib does not.

I am loading the vcpkg toolchain file.

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Edit: based on the below answer and an answer from [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/discussions/32104#discussioncomment-6232284) I'm using the following:

```
    find_package(PkgConfig)

    pkg_check_modules(TAGLIB REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET taglib)

    target_link_libraries(thetarget PRIVATE PkgConfig::TAGLIB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though taglib has some files named `taglib-config.cmake`, it does not support to be used with cmake directly and do not export targets.

Instead, taglib installs package config files. You'll need to use the package config module:

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
```

Then use the package config functions:

```
pkg_check_modules(taglib REQUIRED)
```

Normally it should define variables such as `taglib_INCLUDE_DIR` and `taglib_LINK_LIBRARIES` that you can use to add compile requirements to your targets.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, the error is the same when I use `taglib`. I've updated the question with a bit more information.

Comment: I think taglib don't export configs after all, even if there's a file named `taglib-config.cmake`. It's a horribly misbehaving package, sadly.

Comment: Given [taglib-config.cmake](https://github.com/taglib/taglib/blob/master/taglib-config.cmake) is just a **template** for a shell script. It has a `.cmake` extension, because it is expanded by [configure_file](https://github.com/taglib/taglib/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L128) CMake command.

Comment: @Tsyvarev does that mean that it should be possible to use regular find_package somehow?

@GuillaumeRacicot it works, thank you! I've updated the question with the solution I'm using now with is slightly modified (using `IMPORTED_TARGET`)

Comment: @altschuler: "does that mean that it should be possible to use regular find_package somehow" - No, `find_package` expects a config file to contain a **CMake script**, but file `taglib-config.cmake` has very different semantic (**template for a shell script**). I just explained that `.cmake` extension of that file can be justified. Its name - `taglib-config` - could be justified too: it is exact name of the resulted shell script. But the total name of the file - `taglib-config.cmake` - could really be confusing.